# Installing pgrouting on mac os x

Tags: pgrouting, error, installation, osx

Regarding installing (build) pgrouting

I could install pgrouting-2.0.0 by using a command `brew install pgrouting`
and following this Build manual: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/build.html

But unfortunately when I tried to type the make command, following error occurred:

```
~$make
Scanning dependencies of target apsp_warshall
[  2%] Building C object src/apsp_warshall/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_warshall.dir/apsp.c.o
/Users/username/Build/cpp/pgrouting-git/src/apsp_warshall/src/apsp.c:14:10: fatal error: 'executor/spi.h' file not found
#include "executor/spi.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/apsp_warshall/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_warshall.dir/apsp.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/apsp_warshall/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_warshall.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I couldn't figure out why this is happened and have any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that current "master" branch encountered above error.

If possible, could you use "develop" branch?

You can download "develop" branch as ZIP file from https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/archive/develop.zip

Comment: Dear Sanak,Thank you! I just download "develop" branch zip binary,yet still same issues was occurred..After download it,what should I do next? Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Okay,after download it,then I have to use "develop" branch for build. This will be first time to switch a branch.I check it out! Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: The direct link to the ZIP file is https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/archive/develop.zip

Comment: Finally I could install pgrouting! I couldn't figure out but it's impossible installing it by homebrew. So I installed it from source.

Comment: Okay, I switched my Mac build environment from macports to homebrew and confirmed that homebrew pgrouting Formula doesn't work correctly.I am asking to last committer about it. (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35515#issuecomment-107855841 ). Thanks,